# Is it possible to hide the browser window's scrollbars without affecting the scrollability of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

<sub>Note: I'm using the most recent version of Chrome.</sub>

I'm working on a web application that utilizes a lot of JavaScript powered layouts. The main issue I'm having is that some layouts makes the window's vertical scrollbar appear (as the content overflows the window), which affects the width of the page during the layout process. I'm working around this issue in most cases by calling the layout function twice - the first call makes the scroll bars appear, and the second one utilizes the correct width of the page. It's still the most recurring headache though.

I'd like to fix this issue by removing the default scrollbar completely, then implement a light custom scrollbar that transparently floats *above* the content instead of affecting the width of the page. I can't seem to remove the window's scrollbars though, without also making scrolling impossible even using the mouse wheel. [Here is a JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/xmrFr/).

As you can see, using `overflow-y: hidden` hides the scrollbar but makes scrolling impossible, and `overflow-y: visible` makes scrollbars appear. Is it possible to hide the window's scrollbars without affecting the scrollability of the window?

*Please note:* I'm talking about the scrollbars of the browser window, not the scrollbars of scrollable elements within it. The two are very different, both when it comes to performance and when it comes to behaviour in different browsers and on mobile platforms.

---

#### My musings.

I can see a couple of ways of making this happen.

1. I can use JavaScript to get the height of the body tag, then emulate scrolling and my custom scroll bar. I'm pretty sure I'd prefer the browser to do its native scrolling though, both for performance and cross-platform compatibility reasons. I'm fairly sure this would also screw with swipe scrolling on mobile browsers.
2. In newer versions of WebKit I can hide scrollbars using CSS: `body::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none; }`. This is perfect, but it won't help Opera or Firefox users. (Screw IE users.)

As you can see, neither of these ways are good ways, so I really need your input.

Comment: Are you looking for a JS-powered scrollbar replacement? It seems like that's what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Terry: Possibly. I have never seen a JS-powered scrollbar replacement that can replace the window scrollbar though.

Comment: Oh yes, plenty of them ;) http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/, http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/ and http://jamesflorentino.github.com/nanoScrollerJS/, just to name a few.